# How to get coverage per test in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm having difficulties to set up my project in a way so SonarQube reports test coverage per test.

During the analysis with Sonar Scanner I just see

```
No information about coverage per test.
```

after reading the JaCoCo execution data.

What are the requirements for this to work? How would a minimal example look that shows coverage per test.

My current environment looks like this:

- SonarQube 6.4
- SonarJava 4.12.0
- Sonar Scanner 3.0.3
- Eclipse Neon
- EclEmma 3.0.0/JaCoCo 0.7.9

And my test project looks like this:

```
Workspace
+- EclipseProject
|  +- bin
|  |  +- foo
|  |  |  +- FooClass.class
|  |  +- tests
|  |     +- FooTestClass.class
|  +- src
|     +- foo
|     |  +- FooClass.java // Class with getter/setter for a private 
|     |                   // instance variable.
|     +- tests
|        +- FooTestClass.java // Two JUnit 4 tests: test1 checks getter,
|                             //                    test2 checks setter.
|
+- xml
|  +- TEST-tests.xml // Export from Eclipse after combined test run, converted to fit Surefire format.
|
+- coverage
|  +- test1.exec // Session export from Eclipse after single test run.
|  +- test2.exec // Session export from Eclipse after single test run.
|
+- sonar-project.properties
```

As you can see, the execution data is present per test. The content of `sonar-project.properties` looks like following:

```
sonar.projectKey=EclipseProject
sonar.projectName=EclipseProject
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0-20170830
sonar.projectBaseDir=/path/to/Workspace
sonar.sources=src/foo/
sonar.tests=src/tests/
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.source=1.8
sonar.java.binaries=bin/
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=/absolute/path/to/coverage/test1.exec,/absolute/path/to/coverage/test2.exec
sonar.junit.reportPaths=/absolute/path/to/xml/
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
```

I'm not sure what's missing. Maybe files need to be named in a specific way like for test results (only picks up `TEST-*.xml` reports in the Surefire format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Sonar Java plugin being open source I found the problem:

```
  private boolean analyzeLinesCoveredByTests(String sessionId,
                      ExecutionDataStore executionDataStore) {

    int i = sessionId.indexOf(' ');
    if (i < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    String testClassName = sessionId.substring(0, i);
    String testName = sessionId.substring(i + 1);
    InputFile testResource = javaResourceLocator
                                .findResourceByClassName(testClassName);
    ...
```

The ID of the dumped session must be of the form `testClassName testName` (e.g., in my case that would be `tests.FooTestClass test1` for test1). Only then will you see test coverage information in SonarQube.